# From IIS get the route the client request took

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

From within IIS server code (C#), is there a way to get what `'tracert server'` on the client would yield?

Simply put, how do I get the route the request took from the client to the server?

Comment: HTTP is way a to high-level protocol for getting or knowing about packet routes. Plus, if it were possible to know the route of a packet on the server then NSA would have a field day.

Comment: How about a reverse trace route? [link](http://ping.eu/traceroute/). Not sure how to do that in c# code though